# Linq - как бы объединить в одно условие

Tags: c#, linq

Как бы объединить в одно условие вот такой набор правил:

```
 public class Entry
 {
    public List<string> Paths;
    ..
 }
 public class ExtList
 {
    public string Name;
    ..
 }
        ObservableCollection<Entry> __Entry = ..
        ObservableCollection<ExtList> __ExtList = ..

        List<String> __ls = (from x in __Entry
                where x.Paths.Count > 0 &&
                      x.Paths.Last().Contains('.') &&
                     !x.Paths.Last().StartsWith(".")
                select Path.GetExtension(x.Paths.Last())).ToList();
        List<String> __lsuniq = (from x in __ls
                    orderby x
                    select x).Distinct().ToList();
        __lsuniq.ForEach(x => __ExtList.Add(new ExtList(x)));
```

Задача вынуть уникальные расширения файлов из списка.

Данные в Entry Paths это разделенный список пути и имени файла, делиться по сепаратору директорий. Например:

```
   [0] = directory1
   [1] = dir2
   [2] = file.ext
```

ExtList пустой, в него надо положить.
Остальные данные в Entry значения не имеют, они не участвуют в условиях отбора.

Comment: Приведите примеры данных, которые находятся в исходных списках, чтобы было нагляднее. Вот там где у вас отточия у  __Entry и __ExtList И выходных тоже, потому что я например не понимаю, чем вас не устроил простой DIstinct из ExtList для того, чтобы "вынуть уникальные расширения файлов из списка"

Comment: `DIstinct из ExtList` - в ExtList надо положить результат, он пустой. Вопрос обновил, добавил данные.

Comment: Вам подойдёт вариант `var __ExtList = __lsuniq.Select(x => new ExtList {Name = x}).ToList();`? (Я посмотрел в linqpad ваш код и хотя по-прежнему не уверен, что правильно понимаю ваши входные данные - мне кажется, что вы сами в шаге от ответа)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы на шаге от ответа: у вас считается __lsuniq так как вам надо, осталось только правильно присвоить.

Предлагаю два варианта на выбор.

Первый:

```
var __ExtList = __lsuniq.Select(x => new ExtList {Name = x}).ToList();
```

(Полностью код, так как не уверен, что у вас за входные данные):

```
void Main()
{
    var __Entry = new List<Entry>
    {
        new Entry{
            Paths = new List<string> {
                    "[0] = directory1",
                    "[1] = dir12",
                    "[2] = file.ext",
                },
        },
        new Entry{
            Paths = new List<string> {
                    "[0] = directory2",
                    "[1] = dir22",
                    "[2] = file.zip",
                },
        },
        new Entry{
            Paths = new List<string> {
                    "[0] = directory3",
                    "[1] = dir33",
                    "[2] = file2.zip",
                },
        },
    };

    List<String> __ls = (from x in __Entry
                         where x.Paths.Count > 0 &&
                               x.Paths.Last().Contains('.') &&
                              !x.Paths.Last().StartsWith(".")
                         select Path.GetExtension(x.Paths.Last())).ToList();
    __ls.Dump();

    List<String> __lsuniq = (from x in __ls
                             orderby x
                             select x).Distinct().ToList();

    __lsuniq.Dump();

    var __ExtList = __lsuniq.Select(x => new ExtList {Name = x}).ToList();
    __ExtList.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class Entry
{
    public List<string> Paths;
}

public class ExtList
{
    public string Name;
}
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второй вариант вы написали сами:

```
var __ExtList = new List<ExtList>();
__lsuniq.ForEach(x => __ExtList.Add(new ExtList(x)));
__ExtList.Dump();
```

Только чтобы он заработал - нужно добавить конструктор:

```
public class ExtList
{
    public ExtList(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name;
}
```

Либо можно не трогать конструкторы, но тогда записывать так:

```
__lsuniq.ForEach(x => __ExtList.Add(new ExtList {Name = x}));
```

PS. Я не знаю, что у вас ещё за поля в ExtList помимо Name - но в текущем виде мне кажется избыточным создавать `List<ExtList>` когда можно обойтись `List<string>`. Меня учили, что создавать структуры надо как можно более простые, без излишних накладных расходов и - уметь обосновывать зачем нужны более сложные и громоздкие.

Comment: Простите что не по теме, а что это за визуализатор?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Это linqpad - обалдено легковесный блокнотик для c#, мой ежедневный инструмент в котором я черкаю скетчи. Однажды подсев на `.Dump()` вы никогда уже не заходите вернуться на `Console.WriteLine()`. Автор этого приложения - очень известный автор книг по c#.

Comment: спасибо огромное! Пошёл ставить)

Comment: Спасибо, да именно так :)

Comment: `избыточным создавать List<ExtList> когда можно обойтись List<string>` - да, но нужна именно `ObservableCollection` для View, так что придется терпеть избыточность.